Entry to the US after recent travel to Russia by a green card holder
16th April 2024, I visited Russia for educational purposes. I am going to return soon to the US. I am a green card holder. Will I be denied entry by the US Border Security because of the Russian stamp in my passport?

So you did not bother to ask this question before you go? You know Russia has detained multiple US citiizens recently for any reasons right? Yes I know you are not US citizen but still.

@stackoverblown 4 Americans have been wrongfully detained since the start of the war. Two were journalists, one was caught with hash oil.

@JonathanReez That is 4 too many if you asked me.

In the past 50 years there hasn’t been a single instance of Green Card holders being denied re-entry for merely visiting a given country:

During Covid times recent Schengen visitors were banned from traveling to the U.S. but Green Card holders were exempted.
U.S. citizens are banned from traveling to North Korea on a U.S. passport but the ban doesn’t extend to Green Card holders.
There was a ban on travel from certain Middle Eastern countries during the Trump administration but Green Card holders were likewise exempted.
Spending money in Cuba is theoretically banned (and therefore travel to Cuba is de jure banned for US citizens and Green Card Holders) but this law is almost never enforced and I can't find a single case of a Green Card revocation due to visiting that country.

So you should be fine traveling anywhere in the world without worrying about your Green Card.

I believe that there have been cases of GC holders getting their cards revoked or having to fight against revocation after visiting Cuba.  I vaguely remember about a case in the last 5 to 7 years, but I can't find it online right now.

@JonathanReez Thanks a lot for your insight

@JonathanReez Thanks for your detailed answer. Helps b´cos the TSA site gives no details

@PeterM that would be highly unusual. You'd first have to be convicted for a prison sentence of at least 1 year for violating the Cuba sanctions, only then could you Permanent Residency be revoked. I can't find any references to this happening.

"I can't find a single case of a Green Card revocation due to visiting that country": probably because the consequence of violating the Cuba sanctions do not include loss of permanent resident status (and felony prosecutions for violating the embargo are rare to virtually nonexistent).  But anyway a green card holder can't be summarily refused admission to the US at the discretion of an immigration officer.  The green card holder has to be given a chance to appear before an immigration judge.  Anyone who wasn't was most likely talked into voluntarily relinquishing permanent residence.


Will I be denied entry by the US Border Security because of the Russian stamp in my passport?

There is nothing (yet) in the rules that would preclude a visitor to Russia from entering the US.

I had appreciated your answer before but somehow that does not show up anymore. I`d said "Thanks and I do hope it stays that way"
